# Can't run truffle migrate if ganache-cli launched with --db option

Tags: truffle

If I run `ganache-cli` without options or any options except `--db`, and then run `truffle migrate` it will successfully migrate my contracts.

BUT

If I run `ganache-cli --db ./ganachedata`, and then run `truffle migrate` it will halt for a while and then crash with error:

`Using network 'development'.
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0x2a1435cdef2ae87c905ed3d8e48a6011c56287fa9d2e8efc1fcdf32bbac979ab
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:328377:30
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:64331:21
    at Array.forEach ()
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:64330:32
    at Array.forEach ()
    at Object.onMessage [as callback] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:64328:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:330526:20
    at Array.forEach ()
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:330525:12
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176198:11`

How to fix it? I need to save blockchain data so I need this --db option.

Btw MetaMask works fine with `ganache-cli --db ./ganachedata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to use `-d` to determinalistic generate account addresses and `-i` to use the same network id.

> ganache-cli -d --db data -i 123456