# How can I take a snapshot of Ganache or Truffle Develop state and reload later?

Tags: truffle, testrpc, testing, ganache-cli, snapshot

I would like to be able to save the state of my local Ganache or Truffle Develop chains into some sort of file. At a later time, I would like to be able to restart Ganache or Truffle Develop and apply the snapshot. Is this possible? Any resources for doing so without extensive digging and tinkering?

Answer (score 15):

This can be done with the `ganache-cli` `db` command. For example, to run a setup similar to the GUI client, I do

```
ganache-cli --db="./data/save/" -i="5777" -d --mnemonic="YOUR_12_WORDS_HERE"
```

Which will save the network data to the `./data/save` directory. If the data is already present in that directory, it will return to the same state (provided `deterministic` and `mnemonic` are set to generate the same genesis block).

I recommend keeping one directory as a backup for your desired state, and then duplicating that file before starting up so that you can always go back to that exact state. (It may be possible to delete individual files in the save directory, but I'm not sure.)

More details at the [ganache-cli repo](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli)

Comment: can we use the above command in the middle when the ganache is running?

Comment: If I have some data in the --db dir, and suppose I run a test, will what I do in the test be saved in the dir? 

I would like to have a snapshot from which I can continually start from the same place

Comment: -d and -i are very important. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/37729/77053

Answer (score 1):

This is now done by using [Ganache workspaces](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/ganache/workspaces/creating-workspaces) with 0 tinkering needed :)