# ganache-cli: how to persist new created accounts

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ganache

I start my service by:

```
ganache-cli -d --gasPrice 0 -q --db=./db
```

This persists my 10 defaults created accounts, but when I create new accounts using Web3:

```
web3.eth.personal.newAccount('password')
```

All the created accounts desapears after I restart the Ganache CLI command. So I cannot unlock this accounts.
But all my erc20 token balance are there.

How can I persist the new created accounts?

Comment: You do not have the -i parameter (network id), it might be the case that it is different between invocations https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/40226.

Answer (score 3):

Command-line option `-d` does not persist your accounts.  It just generates them deterministically, i.e. the same addresses are generated every time you run it.  Here is what [documentation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#using-ganache-cli) says about this:

> `-d` or `--deterministic`: Generate deterministic addresses based on a pre-defined mnemonic.

I doubt `ganache` is able to persist accounts at all, because it was designed for clean-room testing.

Comment: It allows persistence of blockchain data if you use the same parameters -i, -d and -db in each invocation. But I'm not sure if the accounts details are part of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Account won't be persistent when you rerun the ganache-cli