# why the below error is thrown when doing transaction with metamask to the truffle

Tags: web3js, truffle, transactions, metamask, ethjs

[image]the error is thrown is shown in the below picture.While doing the transaction an error stating ethjs-rpc with payload["id:761..,Jsonrpc:"2.0","params":"0xf8..]

Comment: Are you interacting with ganache? In that case a common problem is a nonce missmatch between metamask and ganache, try resetting the metamask account.

Comment: yes i am interacting with truffle blockchain, reseting the accounts sometimes work and sometimes when i reset the account then this message is displayed ALERT: Gas limit must be at least 21000. when i alter the gas limit through advance settings of the metamask and process the transaction then above error in pic is shown. when i use truffle blockchain alone then resetting the accounts works but when truffle blockchain connected with ganache gives error shown above in pic.Please help@Ismael sir.

Comment: Another try is to run ganache with persistent state so every time you launch you will have the same accounts and contracts, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40153/how-can-i-take-a-snapshot-of-ganache-or-truffle-develop-state-and-reload-later/40226#40226.