# Truffle migrate hangs when I run ganache with the --db flag

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, ganache

From the command line, when I run the following command:

```
ganache-cli --db ~/Documents/Ethereum/ --mnemonic "bride forest screen jazz injury grit rather seek also donate media mechanic"
```

and I run "truffle migrate" in my project directory then it hangs for a while and produces the following output:

```
Could not connect to your Ethereum client. Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle.js)
```

The following link does not solve the problem as it produces the same result:

[Can't run truffle migrate if ganache-cli launched with --db option](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37597/cant-run-truffle-migrate-if-ganache-cli-launched-with-db-option)

truffle migrate works fine when the --db option is omitted from the ganache-cli call. Why is the --db option causing truffle migrate to hang?